# How to delete named macros?

Tags: emacs, macros

I know you can delete the last macro from the macro ring with C-x C-k C-d, but how do I delete a macro that I've already named (and assigned to a key in .emacs)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To delete the named macro, hit <kbd>M-:</kbd> and type `(fmakunbound 'name-of-macro)`.  (I couldn't find any interactive command to do that.)

To unbind the key, use <kbd>M-x</kbd> `global-unset-key` and enter the key binding.

Comment: The debugger is giving me a void function error for fmakunbond. ... Turns out macros are only temporary, even named ones: they're cleared once I restart emacs. This is good enough for me :)

Comment: Oops, I misspelt `fmakunbound` :)